# Separate each word from an element with a string sentence, but there are some spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm feeling a little newbie with this problem...

Ok, facing this example:

```
<h1>A<span>really</span>long<span>sentence</span></h1>
```

I need to dynamically place each word in an array, however i need to keep the order. Something like:

```
var words = ['A','really','long','sentence'];
```

My original idea was to get all spans into an array, and all words without span into another array, and then merge both, however, i'm not seeing any javascript/jQuery method to properly collect the words without spans into an array.

I'm sure I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, you don't want to name your variable Array.

Comment: @Jordan i know! it was just for educational purposes =) still i will edit to avoid confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spans make it messy; you have turn the spans into spaces, then split on space.

```
var array = $('h1').html().replace(/\<\/*span\>/g,' ').split(' ');
```

Comment: and that was the basic stuff i was missing! i knew the solution was easy but i couldn't remember! (I probably would if i've learned RegEx by now...really need to!) Thanks! =)

Comment: I highly recommend [rubular](http://rubular.com) to learn regex. I imagine there is a JS specific version available somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wordgrab(node){
    var A= [];
    if(node){
        node= node.firstChild;
        while(node!= null){
            if(node.nodeType== 3){
                if(/[a-zA-Z]/.test(node.data)){
                    A= A.concat(node.data.split(/\s+/));
                }
            }
            else A= A.concat(wordgrab(node));
            node= node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

wordgrab(document.body)// use any parent node

Answer (score 0):

While it is always best to use plain JS where possible, it is also a nasty thing to try to parse HTML reliably. Since jQ is already in use here, I'd stick with $.fn.text():

```
var a = $( '<h1>A <span>really</span> long <span>sentence</span></h1>' ).text().split( /\W+/ );
```

Comment: I suppose that is a trick. But it also means your markup structure is whack, IMO. :)

Comment: Probably in you honest opinion. Probably not facing the intention on the final result. http://jsfiddle.net/kg7tw/